# How to expand control sequence in argument of a macro

Tags: macros, tex-core, expansion

Consider the following:

```
\def\foo#1#2 {%
  \if#1a%
    \message{#2}
  \fi}
\def\x{abc}
\edef\y{\foo\x}
\y
```

The result: `! Argument of \foo has an extra }.`

The expected result: `bc`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TeX doesn't expand tokens when it's absorbing arguments to a macro. So `\foo` finds `}` when still looking for its second argument after having decided that `\x` is the first one.

If your aim is to have the second argument to `\foo` delimited by a space you should do

```
\def\foo#1#2 {%
  \if#1a%
    \message{#2}
  \fi}
\def\x{abc }
\edef\y{\expandafter\foo\x}
\y
```

so that `\x` is expanded before `\foo` starts looking for its arguments.

The macro `\y` will expand to `\message{bc}`. Note the trailing space in the replacement text for `\x`.

---

The delimiter you chose is not the best one in this particular occasion. A different strategy is to use a “reserved” token:

```
\def\foo#1#2\foo{%
  \if#1a%
    \message{#2}
  \fi}
\def\x{abc}
\edef\y{\expandafter\foo\x\foo}
\y
```

I used `\foo` because it's unlikely that it appears in the argument to itself.

Comment: Is it possible not to use any delimiter at all, but instead just to take the whole expansion of `\x` ? Can we do without adding space to `\def\x` ? What if `\def\x{abc }` will be `\edef\x{\fontname\font}` - I don't want this to contain any additional delimiter data. Simply leaving the space out produces just `b`, but I need `bc`.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko An argument is either delimited or undelimited. You can't have both for the same parameter.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko Maybe you need something like `\def\foo#1{\expandafter\fooA#1\fooA} \def\fooA#1#2\fooA{...}`. Then you can use `\foo\x` and `\x`  includes "pure data" without delimiter.